# Number to String conversion function in ABAP

Tags: abap

I want to show a message of type E for which I have to first create a string. The string has mixed string and integer variables to be joined.

Since only strings can be concatenated, I copy integer variable into string variable, make a whole string and concatenate.

Is there a conversion function such as to_string(integer_variable) that can convert integers to string?

```
PROGRAM abc.
DATA: im_acc_no TYPE i VALUE 100,
      lv_acc_no TYPE string,
      lv_msg TYPE string.
START-OF-SELECTION.
      lv_acc_no = im_acc_no.
      CONCATENATE 'Acnt# ' lv_acc_no ' does not exist' INTO lv_msg.
      MESSAGE lv_msg TYPE 'E'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying variables inside message statement in ABAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958202/displaying-variables-inside-message-statement-in-abap)

Comment: Might also be helpful: [Is there another way to concatenate instead of using the CONCATENATE keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860281/is-there-another-way-to-concatenate-instead-of-using-the-concatenate-keyword)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `CONV` operator ([SAP help](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenconstructor_expression_conv.htm)) which can do something similar to `to_string` but it is not allowed in the `CONCATENATE`, so won't help you in your scenario.

You could use the `&&` operator ([SAP help](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenstring_operators.htm)) to create the message in-place in the `MESSAGE` command like:

```
 MESSAGE |Acnt# | && lv_acc_no && | does not exist| type 'E'.
```

Side note: do not use this variant of the MESSAGE command, it might be easy to program but it makes it hard to investigate where a message is being generated. For this reason it is better to actually create a message in SE91 and use that. Variable replacements (&) in the message also handle integers just fine.

Comment: You could also write `|Acnt# {  lv_acc_no } does not exist|`. Placing variables inline using `{` and `}` also gives you [a bunch of useful format options](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_cp_index_htm/CLOUD/en-US/abapcompute_string_format_options.htm).